# How to organize java 8 code with Functional interfaces

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have recently started reading about java 8 features and i am confused with what seems like a very basic thing. How to organize code in 'Functional style' ?
Whatever i do, it looks very object oriented to me.

Best to explain what i ask with an example.

```
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface SubstringOperator {

        String splitAtLastOccurence(String plainText, String delimiter);

    }
```

Let's say that in certain `class` i always need exactly one specific implementation of the `SubstringOperator` interface. I could provide implementation in the constructor like below:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private SubstringOperator substringOperator;

    public SomeClass() {

        substringOperator = (s, d) -> { return s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(d)+1);};
    }
}
```

I could now use this implementation in any method within `SomeClass` like this:

```
 //...
String valueAfterSplit = substringOperator.splitAtLastOccurence(plainText, "=");
```

If i now wish to add another class which reuses that specific `SubstringOperator` implementation, should i create another class which exposes the implementation via getters?

Am i missing something obvious, or:

- functions must be contained in classes in order to reuse them ?
- How is that any different than object oriented paradigm ?

Put aside Stream API and other thingies, i would like to get basic understanding about code organization in java 8 for Functional style programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it's better to reuse existing functional interfaces instead of creating new ones. In your case the [`BinaryOperator<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) is what you need. And it's better to name the variables by their meaning, not by their type. Thus you may have:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private BinaryOperator<String> splitAtLastOccurence = 
        (s, d) -> s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(d)+1);
}
```

Note that you can simplify single-statement lambda removing the `return` keyword and curly brackets. It can be applied like this:

```
String valueAfterSplit = splitAtLastOccurence.apply(plainText, "=");
```

Usually if your class uses the same function always, you don't need to store it in the variable. Use plain old method instead:

```
protected static String splitAtLastOccurence(String s, String d) {
    return s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(d)+1);
}
```

And just call it:

```
String valueAfterSplit = splitAtLastOccurence(plainText, "=");
```

Functions are good when another class or method is *parameterized* by function, so it can be used with different functions. For example, you are writing some generic code which can process list of strings with additional `other` string:

```
void processList(List<String> list, String other, BinaryOperator<String> op) {
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        list.set(i, op.apply(list.get(i), other));
    }
}
```

Or more in java-8 style:

```
void processList(List<String> list, String other, BinaryOperator<String> op) {
    list.replaceAll(s -> op.apply(s, other));
}
```

In this way you can use this method with different functions. If you already have `splitAtLastOccurence` static method defined as above, you can reuse it using a method reference:

```
processList(myList, "=", MyClass::splitAtLastOccurence);
```

Comment: Thank you, that gave me some much needed context.